# how does scaffold works on ruby? how are the params defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scaffold

I am using scaffold on ruby on rails, and its great and all, makes everything simpler, but I dont understand one thing and the books or the web dont have a clear solution.

For exmaple, I use scaffold and I create table user and I can make /user/1 and I will see the user with the ID 1 , and if i make /user/edit/1 I will edit user with ID number 1, but on the controller the code its like this

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

According the MVC Ive worked, the controller is the first in respond, so, in some way I should be able to indicate to use the **show** method, but how? I dont have anything else added on my routes file. any idea??

Answer (score 1):

The default routes are "HTTP Verb: GET, Path: /photos/:id, Action: show, Used For: display a specific photo". See the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Scaffold add `resource :users` in your `routes.rb` file `. This actually enables all RESTfull routes. You can see the default routes in [this table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) (bellow). This is what is defined as **convention over configuration**, and it is because of this that rails is magical. Once you master a few conventions, your will be able to do more with less.

[table http://i.imm.io/150CI.png](http://i.imm.io/150CI.png)

By the way, this is a really nice site to use if you are planning to learn Rails. I'm not aware of a better source, even books.